# calculating lots of statistics on database user data: optimizing performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, performance, postgresql

I have the following situation (in Rails 3): my table contains financial transactions for each user (users can buy and sell products). Since lots of such transactions occur I present statistics related to the current user on the website, e.g. current balance, overall profit, how many products sold/bought overall, averages, etc. (the same also on a per month/per year basis instead of overall). Parts of this information is displayed to the user on many forms/pages so that the user can always see his current account information (different bits of statistics is displayed on different pages though).

My question is: how can I optimize database performance (and is it worth it)? Surely, if the user is just browsing, there is no need to re-calculate all of the values every time a new page is loaded unless a change to the underlying database has been made?

My first solution would be to store these statistics in their own table and update them once a financial transaction has been added/edited (in Rails maybe using :after_update ?). Taking this further, if, for example, a new transaction has been made, then I can just modify the average instead of re-calculating the whole thing.

My second idea would be to use some kind of caching (if this is possible?), or to store these values in the session object.

Which one is the preferred/recommended way, or is all of this a waste of time as the current largest number of financial transactions is in the range of 7000-9000?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to investigate summary tables, also known as materialized views.

This link may be helpful:

http://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Materialized_Views

Comment: Though with only 9000 transactions this is probably not necessary.

Comment: Thanks this was just what I was looking for. I tried to use ActiveRecord callbacks which also worked but then decided against them  because of potential scalability issues later on. While reading about materialized views I came across the book 'Enterprise Rails' which is a great read!